# Extracting the Year, month and date with different locale

Tags: c++, mfc, internationalization, locale

I have an application in which allow users to query some data based on date. The application supports different westerns languages and the user is allowed to input the query in their format.

the various formats includes

```
15.10.2012
15/10/2012
10/15/2012
15-Oct-2012
15-Okt-2012
```

The last one is a different language and the look up table doesn't fit well for this because I need to define the lookup tables to the N number of languages I support.

I believe there could be some solution MFC/C++ Library/Windows platform itself to extract the date information in various valid format. Please help if there are some libraries/APIs sort of.

Comment: Perhaps (just perhaps) it would be an idea to have users enter their date following international standards, i.e. ISO 8601... I feel that any "localized" parsing is *bound* to give problems, through badly set locale and/or ambiguous formats (like in example #2 / #3). That's why ISO 8601 was invented in the first place...

Comment: Just FWIW, what I meant is making yyyy-mm-dd the mandatory format.

Comment: Try to look at COleDateTime::ParseDateTime(). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/37t16xc9(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 3):

In most of the modern GUIs the user are not required to enter the date/time by keying-in. Usually there are some sort of calender controls which helps the user to enter the date-time. Can't you use some of these controls (for e.g : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hhdec0z1(v=vs.80).aspx) to restrict the user input? And you can always display the date/time back to the user in the current locale using the microsoft function strftime().

Comment: `strftime()` is Standard C, not Microsoft.

Comment: @DevSolar : I misunderstood that.. sorry

Comment: The UI is pretty old and can't really change the way it works. Also a calendar control can't be put there :) so have to live with it :D  Thanks for your reply. Apparently there was a library (custom one) which helped to solve the problem but as @Dmitry mentioned, COleDateTime helps me to solve it. Thanks.

Comment: I have seen the pain of working with such legacy UIs. Best of luck... ;)